# Concatenation vs Interleaving

Tags: sas

I cannot understand the difference between `interleaving` and `concatenation`

Interleaving

```
proc sort data=ds1 
           out=ds1;
   by var1;
run;
proc sort data=ds2 
           out=ds2;
   by var1;
run;
 data testInterleaving ; 
 set ds1 ds2 ;
 run ;
```

Concatenation

```
data testConcatenation; 
   set ds1 ds2;
run;
```

I tested these and the resulting datasets were exactly the same except for the order of observations which I think does not really matter. The two resulting datasets contain exactly the same observations. So, what is the difference, except for order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interleaving, as CarolinaJay notes, is combining `SET` with `BY`.  It is not merging, and it is not just sorting prior to setting.

For example, let's create a pair of datasets, the female and the male members of `sashelp.class`.

```
data male female;
set sashelp.class;
if sex='F' then output female;
else output male;
run;

proc sort data=male;
by name;
run;
proc sort data=female;
by name;
run;

data concatenated;
set male female;
run;

data interleaved;
set male female;
by name;
run;
```

Now, look at the datasets.  `Concatenated` is all of the males, then all of the females - it processes the `set` statements in order, exhausting the first before moving onto the second.

`Interleaved` is in name order, not in order by sex.  That's because it traverses the two (in this case) `set` datasets by name, keeping track of where it is in the `name` ordering.  You can add debugging statements (Either use the data step debugger, or add a `put _all_;` to the datastep) to see how it works.

Answer (score 3):

SAS defines [INTERLEAVING](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001318366.htm) as using a BY statement with a SET statement. The included link shows two data sets, sorted by the same variable(s), generating one data set using a BY statement with a SET statement.

Answer (score 1):

The data steps at the end are the exact same.  You are performing the same code, it doesn't matter if you sort before hand.

What I think you mean in the interleaving is

```
data testInterleaving ;
MERGE ds1 ds2;
by var1;
run;
```

The `set` statement reads sequentially through the data sets in the order you list them.  The `merge` statement compares records between the sets and puts them into the output in the order of the variable(s) in the `by` statement.  I recommend looking at the SAS documentation on the `merge` statement as this is a very simplistic explanation for a very powerful tool.

Comment: Interleaving is a distinct concept from merging.

Comment: Gathered that from @CarolinaJay65 's answer.  Also why I voted up her answer!